# What is the definition of locally finite random subset?

Tags: probability-theory

Reading [a reply by Didier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34033/laplace-functional-of-a-point-process/34066#34066), I was wondering

1. How is a "random subset" defined? Is
   it a measurable mapping, i.e., [random
   element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_element), from a probability space
   to the power set of another set,
   with respect to some sigma
   algebra(?) defined on the power set?
2. How is a random subset being locally
   finite defined?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure

Comment: @Rasmus: are you talking about random subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A random subset $\mathcal{N}$ being (almost surely) locally finite means that $\#(\mathcal{N}\cap B)$ is (almost surely) finite for every compact subset $B$ of the target space. In the setting of point processes, one considers only (almost surely) locally finite random subsets $\mathcal{N}$ so, in a way, one avoids at all cost the power set of the target space, which is much too *big* for measurability purposes.

The distribution of a  locally finite random subset $\mathcal{N}$ is defined by the distributions of the finite families of integer valued random variables $\#(\mathcal{N}\cap B)$ for compact subsets $B$, just like the distribution of an infinite sequence $(\xi_n)_n$ indexed by the integers is defined by the distributions of the random vectors $(\xi_n)_{n\in I}$ for every finite $I$, aka the marginals of the process. Note in particular that one assumes that $\#(\mathcal{N}\cap B)$ is measurable for every compact $B$.

When $\#(\mathcal{N}\cap B)$ is almost surely finite for every compact $B$, one can identify the random subset $\mathcal{N}$ with the random measure which puts a unit Dirac mass on every point in $\mathcal{N}$, defined formally bas the unique measure $N$ such that, at least for every measurable bounded function $f$ with bounded support,
$$
\int f(x)\, \mathrm{d}N(x)=\sum_{x\in\mathcal{N}}f(x).
$$
This identification goes through the (trivial) remark that, for every measurable subset $B$, the events $[\mathcal{N}\cap B=\emptyset]$ and $[N(B)=0]$ coincide.

Comment: Thanks! When talking about bounded subset of the target space, what kind of space is the target space assumed to be to make the boundedness meaningful? I saw on Wikipedia for a point process, it is assumed to be a locally compact second countable Hausdorff space equipped with its Borel σ-algebra, but as far as I know, we need metric space, topological vector space or partial ordered set to define boundedness of a subset.

Comment: Replace *bounded* by *compact*.